# Localhost shows noting in xampp 1.8.2

Tags: php, xampp

I installed xampp 1.8.2. but when i browse using `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1` then it shows noting. But when i browse using my ip like (192.168.10.71) then it works whats the problem.

Why localhost shows noting.

[image: I have attached my control panel screenshot]

Please Advice me.

Answer (score 0):

Read this carefully:
[click me](http://dalibor.dvorski.net/downloads/docs/InstallingConfiguringDevelopingWithXAMPP.pdf)

If this doesnt help - check your PATH variable(you need /path/to/htdocs) and remember to shutdown skype(which will free up port 80).